# MSSQL JOIN Query - Incorrect Syntax Near 'Value'

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a query for which I have not visually seen syntax or formatting errors.

However upon execution, SSMS reports that there is a syntax error near 'Value'.

```
select * from sw.Users u 
join sw.Locations l 
join sw.Organizations o 
on u.LocationID = l.LocationID 
and l.OrganizationID = o.OrganizationID 
and o.OrganizationName = 'Value'
```

Error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 38 Incorrect syntax near 'Value'.

Trying the following works with results:

```
select * from sw.Users u 
join sw.Locations l 
on u.LocationID = l.LocationID
```

Why is the first join query reporting the error?

Comment: Theoretically you _could_ make this work with a nested join structure but it's a very bad habit because it makes queries harder to maintain (to read). A nested join would look like such: `select * from sw.users u join sw.locations l join sw.organizations o on l.organizationid = o.organizationid on u.locationid = l.locationid where o.organizationname = 'value';` but, as I said, you're better off learnin and using the standard join syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first join is missing a join condition. The [syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx) is: `a JOIN b ON ...`, not just `a JOIN b`.

If you are joining three tables, you need to do that in two steps, either

```
(a JOIN b ON ...) JOIN c ON ...
```

or

```
a JOIN (b JOIN c ON ...) ON ...
```

Note that the parenthesis are optional, which is probably the reason why the error message says "near Value" - SQL Server assumes that you mean to use the second syntax and misses the second `ON` at the end of your statement.

The first syntax is usually easier to read. Personally, I'd write your SQL statement as follows:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM sw.Users AS u 
       INNER JOIN sw.Locations AS l ON u.LocationID = l.LocationID 
       INNER JOIN sw.Organizations AS o ON l.OrganizationID = o.OrganizationID 
 WHERE o.OrganizationName = 'Value'
```

Each JOIN line adds another table, and its ON clause describes the *relationship* between the old result set and the new table. The actual filter criterion is in a WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the "on" after each join.

```
select * from sw.Users u 
join sw.Locations l 
on u.LocationID = l.LocationID 
join sw.Organizations o 
on l.OrganizationID = o.OrganizationID 
where o.OrganizationName = 'Value'
```

Have a look [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191430(v=sql.105).aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ON` keyword after each (`INNER`)`JOIN`

```
SELECT  *
FROM    sw.Users            u
JOIN    sw.Locations        l   ON u.LocationID = l.LocationID 
JOIN    sw.Organizations    o   ON l.OrganizationID = o.OrganizationID
                                   AND o.OrganizationName = 'Value'
```

Answer (score 0):

try restructuring like this

```
select * from sw.Users u 
join sw.Locations l    on u.LocationID = l.LocationID 
join sw.Organizations o on
l.OrganizationID = o.OrganizationID 
and o.OrganizationName = 'Value'
```